# Script to trigger Login or Logout onclick div id

Tags: javascript

I need a text: "Log-In/Out" with div ID to show either Login or Logout option whenever I click on it. But it returns "Logout" every time. Please help me out by correcting the code below or any alternative in javascript.

My code is:

```
<div id="My-Button-Action" onclick="myButtonFunction()"> Log-In/Out </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myButtonFunction() {
  var userLoggedIn =  "<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo 'yes';} else { echo 'no';} \>";
 
  if ( userLoggedIn = "no") {
    document.getElementById("My-Button-Action").innerHTML = "<a class='mybutton-class' data-toggle='modal' href='/login'>Log-In</a>";  
  } 
  if ( userLoggedIn = "yes") {
    document.getElementById("My-Button-Action").innerHTML = "<a class='mybutton-class' href='/logout'>Log out</a>";  
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The equality operator is `==` or `===`. `=` is the assignment operator and it returns the value of the right hand side expression. In Javascript, a non-empty `string` is considered truthy (`true`), that's why both of your statements would run.

Comment: Thanks updated, but with == or === does not work the on-clic - nothing happens now..

Answer (score 0):

> The equality operator is == or ===. = is the assignment operator and it returns the value of the right hand side expression. In Javascript, a non-empty string is considered truthy (true), that's why both of your statements would run.

```
<div id="My-Button-Action" onclick="myButtonFunction()"> Log-In/Out </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myButtonFunction() {
        let btn = document.getElementById("My-Button-Action");
        let goLogin ="<a class='mybutton-class' data-toggle='modal' href='/login'>Log-In</a>";
        let goLogout = "<a class='mybutton-class' href='/logout'>Log out</a>";
        var userLoggedIn = "<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo 'yes';} else { echo 'no';} ?>";
        userLoggedIn == "no" ? btn.innerHTML = goLogin : btn.innerHTML = goLogout;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, it looks as expected, but it is not functioning properly: after page load, clicking on the div text: 'Log-In/Out' shows only the 'Logout' (for both visitor & logged in user) option. If I swap the actions between with "yes" logic in the last line, It only shows login.  I check by changing the names of the ID, function, variables but not change.

Comment: **is_user_logged_in(): bool** => *bool* return -> **True** if user is logged in, **False** if not logged in. In the code above, it will show logout only once logged in either visitor or user.